# SSRS Setting Specific Value that includes multiple values

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that I want to offer filtering options. I have a column [Division] with values Division1, Division2, Division3, ect.

I can filter the report using a parameter and choosing from Avaliable Values the Get Values from a query section.

However, I want to include a value that will be a "select all" value that won't apply any filtering.

(I've tried the multiple values box and it also does not work)

Thus I've tried to "Specify Values" for all the values, however I cannot figure out an expression that will include all the values.

I've tried """= Division1 or Division2 or (ect.)""" but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your query that gets data for the paramater add, UNION All, "". In your proc that runs when params are set use logic to view "" as all.

Comment: Does you report use a Stored Proc to get data or a query directly in your dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter query should have a UNION like the one below

```
SELECT '<All values>' As val
UNION ALL
SELECT division
FROM mytable
```

The report parameter doesn't have to be multivalue in order not to apply the filter

In your query WHERE you should have an expression like the one below

```
WHERE (division = @Parameter OR @Parameter = '<All values>')
```

In case you want to use multivalue parameter

```
WHERE (division IN  (@Parameter) OR  '<All values>' IN (@Parameter) )
```

Comment: I am probably doing this wrong, I apologize, I'm still somewhat new to SSRS. I have updated my Parameter query to
`SELECT 'All Values' as val 
UNION ALL Select [Division] From mytable.`

And updated my data query with the new Where statement but when i select 'All Values', my report is coming up blank

Comment: Can you post your Where clause?

Comment: `WHERE (x.Division = @Division OR @Division = 'All Values')`

Comment: The parameter is set to single or multiple value?

Comment: Currently it is set to single, i'd like to just be able to select the parameter value 'All Values' and have that pick up all of the divisions

Comment: I think you should trace and debug the query in management studio

Comment: Figured out that I had an accidental filtering property turned on in my Tablix properties. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should mark "allow multiple values" and add in Specific Value only all possible individual values. Then you will have "select all" value without adding it.